# spring boot RequestBody don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm studying & new to Spring boot, and trying to create a controller receiving post request, but throughout my test the controller always receives null request body object. Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

```
{  
   "user":{  
      "name":"teste",
      "lastName":"teste"
   }   "contact":{  
      "email":"teste@teste.com",
      "phone":"0123456789"
   }   "isMarried":true
}
```

---

Java Class:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value= "/user", consumes= MediaType.ALL_VALUE ) 
public ResponseEntity<Void> login(@RequestBody User user, 
        @RequestBody contact,
        boolean isMarried){ 
    System.out.println(user.getUsername()); 
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED); 
}
```

> sysout is null but isMarried works:(

---

Java Entity:

```
@Entity 
public class User{ 

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name= "id")
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name="name") 
    private String name; 

    @Column(name= "last_name") 
    private String lastName; 

    Getters and setters.... 
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public contact { 

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name= "id") 
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name="email") 
    private String email; 

    @Column(name= "phone") 
    private String phone; 

    Getters and setters.... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestBody` annotation is expected to represent the entire body of the request, and it only binds to one object in the request. So you have to change your input json format, your post method signature, and create a encapsulation class to hold User, Contact & IsMarried data together.

```
{
   "user": {
      "name": "teste",
      "lastName": "teste"
   },
   "contact": {
      "email": "teste@teste.com",
      "phone": "0123456789"
   },
   "isMarried": true
}


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value= "/user", consumes= MediaType.ALL_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<Void> login(@RequestBody UserDetail userDetail){
   System.out.println(userDetail.getUser.getUsername()); 
   return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

class UserDetail{
 User user;
 Contact contact;
 boolean married;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, one more question, if I send only User in the request like: { "user"{:"name":"teste","lastName" }}, it's work?

Comment: Surely it will work, but values for contact detail, and martial status will be null. I will provide the syntax as answer.

Comment: Yes it will work, and your contact object will be null and married boolean will be false. JSON is a key,value pair notation throughout, thus elements are optional, if you don't provide anything and just send `{}`, it will still create `UserDetail` object but empty.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation). Please see [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can send only user details like this.

> {
>         "name": "teste",
>         "lastName": "teste"
>      }

And your request method should look like this.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value= "/user", consumes= MediaType.ALL_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<Void> login(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println(user.getName()); 
    System.out.println(user.getLastName()); 

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Hope this helps.